# Codeigniter Form hidden not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

form helper in codeigniter doesn't send any hidden variables.
Code in View:

```
foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $hidden = array('drop-user-process' => TRUE, 'dropped-user-id' => $row->u_id, 'schoolid' => $schoolInfo[0]->ps_id);
        echo form_open('core/school', '', $hidden);
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th scope="row">'.$i.'</th>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->u_name.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->u_surname.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row->u_email.'</td>';
        if($this->session->userdata('u_id') == $schoolInfo[0]->ps_admin_id) { 
            echo '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Wyrzuć</button></td>'; 
        } else {
            echo '<td><span class="badge badge-secondary">Brak uprawnień</span></td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        $i++;
        echo form_close();
    }
```

And the code in controller (log message returns empty variable "drop-user-process")

```
if(!empty($this->input->post('drop-user-process')) == TRUE)
{
    log_message('debug', 'CORE: school, drop user not empty');
    if($this->core_model->kickUserFromSchool($this->post->input('dropped-user-id'), $this->input->post('schoolid')) == TRUE)
    {
        log_message('debug', 'CORE CONTROLLER: school, return TRUE; school id: '.$this->input->post('schoolid').', kicked user id: '.$this->input->post('dropped-user-id'));
        redirect(base_url('school/'.$this->input->post('schoolid')));
    }
    else
    {
        log_message('debug', 'CORE CONTROLLER: school, return TRUE; school id: '.$this->input->post('schoolid').', kicked user id: '.$this->input->post('dropped-user-id'));
        redirect(base_url('school/'.$this->input->post('schoolid')));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <?php echo form_open();?>
    <?php echo form_hidden('_hidden_field','TEST');?>
    <?php echo form_input('username', 'John');?>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

before using form , you must load form_helper
try this:

```
function some_function() {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $hidden = array('drop-user-process' => TRUE, 'dropped-user-id' => $row->u_id, 'schoolid' => $schoolInfo[0]->ps_id);
    echo form_open('core/school', '', $hidden);
    // do more
}
```

Comment: I have this function in autoload, i'm using form open in other documents, but in this view it doesn't work.